# request when in use authorization not working inspite of adding content into the plist

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

I have built an app that sends the location of the user when he exits a region `CLCircularRegion`. I am using `requestWhenInUseauthorization` method but the prompt that asks the user if the location can be used doesn't pop up, but the location gets updated. My location manager is declared in a custom class inherited to `NSObject` .. and I'm calling this in the view controller class ..

Here is my code:

```
class LocationProcessHandler: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
static let sharedInstance = LocationProcessHandler()
var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    func startLocationUpdates() {
locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters


            if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
               // if self.locationManager.respondsToSelector(#selector(locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization)) {
                self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
                NSLog("The request when in use authorisation is selected")
                    self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
                }
                else {
                    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
                }


        NSLog("Started to monitor the significant location Changes")
    self.locationManager.stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
  self.locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
   // NSLog("the distance filter of the location manager is \(locationManager.distanceFilter)")
    }


func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {


    NSLog("Location Updated")
    let persist = Persistence()

    let currentLocation : CLLocation = locations[0]
    let latitude : Double = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude
    let Longitude : Double = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude
    let regionID = "GeoFenceTrack"
    let region : CLCircularRegion = CLCircularRegion.init(center: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, Longitude), radius: Double(persist.getObject(mdmiosagent_Constants.LOCATIONRADIUS))!, identifier: regionID)

    NSLog("the center of the region is \(region.center) and the redius of the region is \(region.radius)")
    self.sendLocation(currentLocation)
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.locationManager.delegate = self

    self.locationManager.startMonitoringForRegion(region)

}
```

didUpdate method is called but I am not able to see any prompt when either the app is started , or when i disable the location services.. However This gets printed in the log

```
 NSLog("The request when in use authorisation is selected")
```

I am not able to find out what the exact reason might be.

Please Help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like your app is already authorised. Check the app settings under privacy

Comment: I mean , if i have given always for the app , won't the prompt be displayed ? and when I disable location services , why is "Turn on location settings..." prompt not getting displayed ?

Comment: Once the prompt is displayed and answered it isn't displayed again. If it is displayed and the user grants the request then the prompt isn't shown again even if you call `request...`. Similarly if they deny the request,the prompt is never shown again. If the user initially denies and then goes into settings and approves or initially approves and then goes into settings and denies, then your app will gain/lose location access without the prompt being displayed. You can detect a denied status and display your own alert requesting the user to enable location but iOS will never prompt the user.

Comment: Also, if the user has already approved (or denied) "always" access then requesting "when in use" won't display the prompt. You can delete your app and re-install to see the prompt again

Comment: There was a time when the prompt would appear and disappear and wud keep popping up irrespective of whatever i select when i would disable the location services

Comment: Now the prompt is not at all displayed

Answer (score 1):

In the part when you call requestWhenInUseAuthorization, you can use something like this:

```
func startLocationUpdates(){
    ....
    //In my case my target is 8+, for this I don't check to prior version
    if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .NotDetermined{
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }else{
        locationManager(locationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus: CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus())
    }
    ....
}
```

Then you need to implement the delegate of ***CLLocationManagerDelegate***:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {

    if status == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse{
        //Here you have the permission
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }else if status == CLAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined || status == CLAuthorizationStatus.Denied || status == CLAuthorizationStatus.Restricted{
        //Here you can show an alert to the user (ex. to change the settings)
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: NSLocalizedString("Location Disable", comment: ""), message: NSLocalizedString("In order to use this feature you must enable your location services.", comment: ""), preferredStyle: .Alert)

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Cancel", comment: ""), style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)


        let openAction = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Open Settings", comment: ""), style: .Default) { (action) in
            if let url = NSURL(string:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) {
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
            }
        }
        alertController.addAction(openAction)

        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Also did you add to ***Info.plist*** the NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription?

Comment: I did ... and i cannot use alertController and i have to check the version as i have deployment target as ios 7